# Scroll notification message till bottom of fixed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll a notification message till bottom of top fixed menu but the body content continue to scroll and only the notification box will remain fixed to bottom of fixed top menu.
Here is a [**fiddle example:**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/1822/)

html:

```
<div class="menu-fixed">I am a fixed menu! </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">I am the body content of this page
            <div class="notification">I am a notification message! 
                      Scroll me to the bottom of top menu only! and back.</div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.menu-fixed{
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-size:30px;
}

.bodyContent{
    padding-top:120px;
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
    background:lime;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
 }
.notification{
    height: 100px;
    left: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this scrollTo function please?
ty.

Comment: You need to post the script as you have it, in order for us to help you fix it :)

Comment: @Archer I don't have any script so far, I just need one to do that :)

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a "write my code for me" site.  You'll need to try something yourself and let us know if you have problems.  Have a look at the jQuery `scroll()` event handler... http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should get you in the right direction:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var menuHeight = $(".menu-fixed").outerHeight();
        var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowScrollTop > 80) {
            $(".notification").css({ top: windowScrollTop + menuHeight });
        }
        else {
            $(".notification").css({ top: 'auto' });
        }
    });
});
```

I've updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/1823/